# Push file to another repository from another organization with github action

Tags: github-actions

I own two GitHub accounts and would like to push one file from `accountA/repoA` to `accountB/repoB` in an automatic and periodic fashion through GitHub action.

I have come across some tutorials but they seem to be geared towards repositories in the same organization.
A simple simple script example or tutorial would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea would be an action like [`andstor/copycat-action`](https://github.com/andstor/copycat-action).
That would require a Personal Access Token with access to `org2/repo2`

- You [schedule it](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events) on `org1/repo1`
- You configure it to push a file to `org2/repo2`

Comment: Thank you. A concrete and simple example on how to configure it woul really help me here. This is the main issue with which I am struggling with: There are a lot of solutions out there to copy/push files from one repo to another *within* the same organization, but not *across* organizations.

Comment: @mat I don't have much more beside https://github.com/andstor/copycat-action#usage: the idea is to put the org2 name in `dst_owner` and the org2 repo2 name in `dst_repo_name`: the fact that is a different organization should not matter, as long as the action uses a token with the right to modify the target repository.